# How can I operate Django-ORM model singlely?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

My directory structure like:

```
├─bin
├─conf
│  └─django_settings.py
├─docs
├─log
└─src
   └─main.py
   └─models.py
```

In my `main.py`, I want use `django-orm` to read data from my MySQL table `campaign_plan`, but when I tried to run `main.py`, I get this error:

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

How can I successfully get the right data?

### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class CampaignPlan(models.Model):
    campaign_id = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    rule_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    account_id = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'campaign_plan'
        unique_together = (('campaign_id', 'rule_id', 'status'),)
```

### main.py

```
import sys, os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'conf'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "src"))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "django_settings")

from models import CampaignPlan


class AutoManagementService(object):

    def __init__(self, campaign_plan):
        self.campaign_plan = campaign_plan

    def run(self):
        pass

campaign_plans = CampaignPlan.objects.all()
```

Comment: Django requires a setting module to be loaded, check [this](https://github.com/masnun/django-orm-standalone) out

Comment: googling for the error message would have yield the solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up Django:

```
import django

django.setup()
```

Comment: an app also needed